# How to get the date between the from date and to date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-day-picker

I'm working on `DayPicker` to get all the range dates, but I couldn't have any good idea of knowing the dates between the start date and end date.

```js
import { DateRange, DayPicker } from 'react-day-picker'

const [range, setRange] = useState<DateRange | undefined>()

useEffect(() => {
  if(range && range.from && range.to) {
    console.log('range.from', range.from)
    console.log('range.to', range.to)
    // range.from Mon Aug 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
    // range.to Sat Aug 06 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
    // I want get 8/1, 8/2, 8/3, 8/4, 8/5 as string data
  }
}, [range])


return (
  <DayPicker
    mode="range"
    defaultMonth={new Date()}
    selected={range}
    onSelect={setRange}
  />
)
```

Comment: How did you import `<DayPicker/>` component? If I import from `@mui/x-date-pickers` the `mode="range"` prop does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use date-fns and create a function.

```
  const getDatesInRange = (startDate: Date, numberOfDays: number) => {
    const dates: Date[] = [];

    [...Array(numberOfDays + 1)].forEach((_, i) => {
      dates.push(addDays(startDate, i));
    });
    console.log(dates); // For debugging purposes
    return dates;
  };
```

Add an array state `const [dateRangeArray, setDateRangeArray] = useState<Date[]>();`  and and we update the useEffect.

Here is the full code:

```
import { addDays, differenceInDays } from 'date-fns';


// inside the component
  const [range, setRange] = useState<DateRange | undefined>();
  const [dateRangeArray, setDateRangeArray] = useState<Date[]>();

  const getDatesInRange = (startDate: Date, numberOfDays: number) => {
    const dates: Date[] = [];

    [...Array(numberOfDays + 1)].forEach((_, i) => {
      dates.push(addDays(startDate, i));
    });
    console.log(dates); // For debugging purposes
    return dates;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (range && range.to && range.from && dateRangeArray === undefined) {
      let daysDiff = differenceInDays(range.to, range?.from);
      setDateRangeArray(getDatesInRange(range.from, daysDiff));
    }
    if (range && range.from && range.to) {
      console.log('range.from', range.from);
      console.log('range.to', range.to);
      // range.from Mon Aug 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
      // range.to Sat Aug 06 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
      // I want get 8/1, 8/2, 8/3, 8/4, 8/5 as string data
    }
  }, [range]);

  return (
    <div>
      <DayPicker mode='range' defaultMonth={new Date()} selected={range} onSelect={setRange} />
    </div>
  );
```